# Does downvoting cost reputation?

Tags: support, reputation, down-votes

I just downvoted an answer. (In this case because it was more of a comment than an answer.) As soon as I downvoted, I got a -1 in my reputation. Is it supposed to be like this, or is it some technical fault?

Comment: In the [help center](http://physics.stackexchange.com/help): http://physics.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation

Comment: If a posted answer is something that should be posted as a comment, the correct course of action is to fag it as `not an answer`; moderators can then [convert it to a comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71284/convert-to-comment). Note, though, that you should *not* use this with technically incorrect answers (like the one you linked to), which should be downvoted.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, there is a 1 rep point hit for downvoting answers.  There isn't any reputation hit for downvoting questions.

I've noticed that *really bad* answers tend to attract 3-4 downvotes and then the author is motivated to remove the answer.  When an answer that you downvoted is removed you get your reputation back.

The reputation loss does make you think twice about downvoting an answer but don't let it discourage you.  Wrong or poor answers need to be downvoted.

Comment: I think I can take one for the cause, :D

Comment: If you think a posted answer doesn't attempt to answer the question you can flag it as "not an answer".

Comment: You should also explain why you believe that answer is wrong.

Comment: To clarify the previous two comments: if you think an answer is wrong, downvote it and (preferably) leave a comment explaining why, but don't flag it. If it's not even an answer, _then_ you flag it.